# Passing arguments to superclass constructor without repeating them in childclass constructor

Tags: python, oop

```
class P(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
       self.a = a
       self.b = b
class C(P):
    def __init__(self, c):
       P.__init__()
       self.c = c

obj = C(a, b, c) #want to instantiate a C with something like this
```

I want to define `C` class object without rewriting all the `P` class constructor argument in `C`'s constructor, but the above code doesn't seem to work. What is the right approach to do this?

**Clarification:**

The idea is to avoid putting parent class's constructor arguments in child class's constructor. It's just repeating too much. All my parent and child classes have many arguments to take in for constructors, so repeating them again and again is not very productive and difficult to maintain. I'm trying to see if I can only define what's unique for the child class in its constructor, but still initialize inherited attributes.

Comment: do you want to initialize parent class's attributes or not ? If not they you can avoid calling it's constructor

Comment: I do want to initialize parent class's attributes. I think an alternative would be constructing child class with an instance of parent class and the child class's unique arguments.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In Python2, you write

```
class C(P):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super(C, self).__init__(a, b)
        self.c = c
```

where the first argument to `super` is the child class and the second argument is the instance of the object which you want to have a reference to as an instance of its parent class.

In Python 3, `super` has superpowers and you can write

```
class C(P):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super().__init__(a, b)
        self.c = c
```

Demo:

```
obj = C(1, 2, 3) 
print(obj.a, obj.b, obj.c) # 1 2 3
```

Response to your comment:

You could achieve that effect with the *args or **kwargs syntax, for example:

```
class C(P):
    def __init__(self, c, *args):
        super(C, self).__init__(*args)
        self.c = c

obj = C(3, 1, 2)
print(obj.a, obj.b, obj.c) # 1 2 3
```

or

```
class C(P):
    def __init__(self, c, **kwargs):
        super(C, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.c = c

obj = C(3, a=1, b=2)
print(obj.a, obj.b, obj.c) # 1 2 3

obj = C(a=1, b=2, c=3)
print(obj.a, obj.b, obj.c) # 1 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I added Clarification section to explain my question better.

Comment: @Fenwick but if your question is how to initialize C with a and b but without ever providing any value for a and b in some form when calling the initializer, the answer is that you can't.

Comment: Oh I definitely meant something like your updated answer. Not providing any value for a and b doesn't make sense at all. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can call parent class constructor by passing self and required arguments

```
class C(P):
    def __init__(self, a,b,c):
       P.__init__(self,a,b)
       self.c = c
```

Comment: Thanks, I get what you mean. I'm just looking for a better solution/syntax. See Clarification section.