# Passing parameters to frozen super dataclass

Tags: python, immutability, super, python-dataclasses, python-attrs

I have a simple (frozen) dataclass inheritance as follows:

```
from attrs import frozen

@frozen
class Interval:
    left: str
    right: str

@frozen
class RealInterval(Interval):
    def __attrs_pre_init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__("-oo", "+oo")

x = RealInterval()
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/init.html), it looks promising:

> **attrs_pre_init** is automatically detected and run before attrs starts initializing. This is useful if you need to inject a call to super().**init**()

But when I check with `mypy` I get:

```
$ mypy example.py 
example.py:13: error: Missing positional arguments "left", "right" in call to "RealInterval"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

---

Note that this is *not* a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52386330/how-can-i-generically-pass-params-to-super-init):

Comment: attrs doesn't have frozen, did you mean attr?

Comment: Oh, `attrs` isn't built-in - `pip install attrs`

Comment: `mypy` doesn't run your code, and it isn't special-cased to know that the `attrs` module is managing at run-time to avoid calling `__init__` with no arguments.

Comment: @chepner not sure what's your suggestion ?

Comment: I'm not sure using `__attrs_pre_init__` as a replacement for default arguments is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how `attrs` (and for that matter: dataclasses work).

The `__init__` is written for specifically the attributes you're defining for performance reasons.

The easiest solution for your use-case is overriding the attributes:

```py
@frozen
class RealInterval(Interval):
    left: str = "-oo"
    right: str = "+oo"
```

Which gives you:

```
>>> RealInterval()
RealInterval(left='-oo', right='+oo')
>>> RealInterval("foo", "bar")
RealInterval(left='foo', right='bar')
```

The pre_init logic is when you're subclassing classes you don't own, but that need their `__init__` called. That's true for some GUI kits for example.

Comment: thanks - any idea why `dataclass` succeeds in the `mypy` check ?

Comment: The way the comment did it works with attrs too, because it replaces completely the `__init__`. What you tried is using a pre-init hook that would be called by attrs’s `__init__` before it’s initialize the attributes.

Comment: arrrgggh ... I had to *explicitly* say that `@frozen(init=False)` + change to `__init__` (instead of the pre init) ... would you say it is a "bad" solution ? IMHO it looks better and passes mypy

Comment: No you don't have to pass `init=False` in the new APIs – your custom `__init__` should be found automatically. You be the judge – I prefer my code to be declarative. Your solutions becomes problematic once you start subclassing further.

Answer (score 0):

This should work even without `attrs` module

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Interval:
    left: str
    right: str

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class RealInterval(Interval):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__("-oo", "+oo")

x = RealInterval()
```

`__init__` of the subclass runs before `__init__` of the superclass.

This can be done with `attrs` with replacing `@dataclass(frozen=True)` with `@frozen`.

Notice that this overrides the default `__init__` method of the subclass.

Comment: is it doable with `attrs` ?

Comment: Edited the answer, when you replace `@dataclass` with `@frozen` it works

Comment: this is what I originally tried (see the post) ... but I get a mypy error ...

Comment: you got an error when you used `__attrs_pre_init__`, but if you use `__init__` it should work

Comment: actually, using `__init__` produces the exact same mypy error ...

Comment: Ran this code in https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10, and got no issues. This runs with mypy version 0.971 and python 3.10

Comment: I can't seem to use the mypy playground with `attrs` ... I get `error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "attrs"` ... with `dataclass` it works fine